# Newline Spacing in Tabbing Environments

Tags: line-spacing, vertical-spacing, tabbing

In my document I have use a tabbing environment of the form:

```
\begin{tabbing}
 \qquad\qquad\quad\= \kill
 $i$ \> Imaginary unit $\sqrt{-1}$\\[1.5pt]
 $\cos x$ \> Cosine\\[1.5pt]
 $\sin x$ \> Sine\\[1.5pt]
 $\exp(x), e^x$ \> Exponential function\\[1.5pt]
 $\log(x)$ \> Logarithm in base $e$\\[1.5pt]
 $x!$ \> Factorial\\[1.5pt]
\end{tabbing}
```

where after each line I find myself having to include `[1.5pt]` to increase the line spacing/height.  To this end I am wondering if there is a way of temporarily overriding the default inside my tabbing environment?

Comment: `{\addtolength\baselineskip{1.5pt}\begin{tabbing}....... \end{tabbing}}`